# Unable to click a radio button which is in a different frame

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying a click on a radio button which is in a different frame (not in the parent frame). There is no exception when I execute the code below, but surprisingly it is not even clicking on the button as well. Please let me know if you have any thoughts/find any issues in my code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Practise_Radio_Checkbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Learning\\API\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");


            WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();

            browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            browser.manage().window().maximize();


            browser.get("http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm");

            WebElement e1 = browser.findElement(By.name("result2"));


            browser.switchTo().frame(e1);

            browser.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/input[1]")).click();

            browser.quit();


    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. I have checked the below code and it is working for me. Please check it from your end and let me know. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it works on Firefox (even without any explicit waits):

```
WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
```

On Chrome, for some unknown reason, you have to *make the click through javascript*:

```
WebElement red = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='radio' and @value='Red']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)browser;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", red);
```

Also, I had to add an Explicit Wait to wait for the frame to become present:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
WebElement iframe = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("result2")));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to click on radio button, which is in the different frame than parent. I think the problem was, you were trying to switch frame "**By Name** - `findElement(By.name("result2"))"`. I tried it with Xpath. It is working for me and i am able click on radio button "**Red**".

Here is the working code:-

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class iframeradiobutton {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm");

        //Switch to Iframe
        WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/article/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/iframe"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/input[1]")).click();
        System.out.println("Clicked on Radio Button Red");
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();// Iframe is Switched to Main Again

        driver.close(); // Closes the current driver instance. 
    }
}
```

Output For the your Reference
[image]

Comment: thanks for your time :) Though it might sound weird, the code is executing the Print statement and printing in console; but I do not see the radio button checked. It's still unchecked. Just to avoid any confusion, I removed driver.close() statement so that the browser window remains open, but to no avail. Is it clicking on your system and the selection is visible?

Comment: Hi Prabodh - Can you please check, you are using the same code as above. Because it is working fine in my end. I have attached the screenshot for your reference and i am able to select 'Red' Radio button. Please update me on the same.

Comment: I see your code has worked in your system, but instead of using same code, its not working. Only different thing I did apart from your code is to run the test in IE and Chrome (both of the cases, no luck) because FF and Webdriver has compatibility issues. If you don't mind, can you please run your code in IE and/or Chrome?

Comment: @PrabodhGhosh I'm actually able to reliably reproduce your problem in Chrome. Interesting question!

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, at least  I am able to share my pain... These are the things  I did to get rid of the issue: 1. Killed all ChromeDriver sessions, 2. Used all three forms (id, string, web-element) of frame parameter while switching to the frame 3. Tried to interact with other elements in the page and was successful. Now I will try to interact with radio button from other sites; in case I am successful, then there must be some problem with the HTML ; otherwise, I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, I was able to select the "Red" button using Chrome. I am yet to verify it in FF. But IE is still a problem. I am using IE 11 by the way. Also, I have accepted your answer, because I do not have 15 reputations to up vote your answer. But thanks again, it meant a lot!